# Custom multiple gesture on a view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I created two custom gesture recognizer.

1. `PinGestureRecognizer`. this gesture is using for drag the view in horizontal direction.
2. `TagGestureRecognizer`. this gesture is using for increase the height of the view till user drag the view in vertically.

Now, i want to fail one gesture if another gesture got recognized.

Example:

1. if user drag the view horizontally in >=10 pixel  need to recognized `PinGestureRecognizer` and fail `TapGestureRecognizer` and vice versa.

How can i achieve the functionality.

I know iOS7 provide the methods like

- `shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:`
- `shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:`

If its equal to my problem or not i was not able to understand. if its correct means kindly suggest me to get same functionality in iOS4 and above.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` delegate method for the `PinGestureRecognizer`, for example:

```
// To handle not scrolling vertically
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint translation = [panGestureRecognizer translationInView:myView];
    return fabs(translation.y) < fabs(translation.x);
}
```